# remove controller and function name from url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am currently coding in codeigniter and i want to remove the controller and function name from url so that only product slug is displayed in url.
currently my url is like 
`www.example.com/main/singlePage/41/product-slug`
I want the url to be like 
`www.example.com/product-slug`

Comment: CodeIgniter has a good documentation about routes: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I suppose that you are searching product by `$this->uri->segment(3)` or `41`. You have to change your controller/model logic and search product by `slug` instead searching by `id`. Then you can use URL without id in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `routes` for that, In your `application/config/routes.php`.

See the example,

```
$route['{any}']  = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly'
```

Ref: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: it is still not working. main is controller and singlePage is function.

Answer (score 2):

To do this create a "catch all" route `$route['{any}'] = 'controller/function'`
and in this function of the controller get the slug `$slug = $this->uri->uri_string()` and decide what to do based on it.