# CodeIgniter- Hide function name from url with slug

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have one controller  Leads & there are two function

1. Index
2. lead-details

Here is my code

```
class Leads extends CI_Controller {
  public function index(){}
  public function lead_details($slug){}
```

Its working like below

```
www.mysite.com/leads/    This will access to index function
www.mysite.com/leads/lead_details/nice-not-to-have-2
```

Now i want to get the details like

```
www.mysite.com/leads/nice-not-to-have-2
```

I tried this but it confuses with index function

```
$route['leads/(:any)']  = 'leads/lead_details'
```

Note: This is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118151/remove-controller-and-function-name-from-url-codeigniter)

Issue is with index function. How i can do it with application/config/routes.php?

Example: leads/index give me error as it points to lead_details function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct like below:

```
$route['leads/index']  = 'leads';
$route['leads(/:any)'] = 'leads/lead_details$1';
```

A URL with `leads` as the first segment, and anything in the second will be remapped to the `leads` class/controller and the `lead_details` method/function.

If you type :

- Either `yoursite.com/leads` or `yoursite.com/leads/index`, it will route to `index` function of `leads` class.
- `yoursite.com/leads/nice-not-to-have-2` to `leads/lead_details`

**Tested on `CI_VERSION :  '3.0-dev'`**

Comment: Then what difference in www.mysite.com/leads/nice-not-to-have-2  AND www.mysite.com/leads/index...here index is function name

Comment: www.mysite.com/leads/index give me error then as it points to lead_details function

Answer (score 0):

if you want to to be route your controller function
go to config->routes.php
than settlement your routes here like this
$route['routename'] = 'leads/leads-details'; #url function